# What is 'or else' in 'is used alone or else with other'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> This condiment is used alone or else with other ingredients.

if I write this,w hat is this "or else"?

Not a threat?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not a threat.  :-)

It is simply a way of expressing an alternative.  In this case, we need to give the alternatives because some condiments are best used by themselves,  some work best only when used with other ingredients, and some may be used both ways; the condiment being discussed is one that can be used both ways.

However, I would call it a poorly-worded sentence; as written, it simply spells out a logical tautology ("if it's not used by itself, then it's used with other things").  Instead, I would suggest something like

> This condiment may be used alone, or with other ingredients.
>
> This condiment works well whether it's used alone or with other ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, "else" is used as it should be - to mean "alternatively"

ie. "This condiment is used alone, or alternatively with other ingredients"

When used as a threat, what follows'else' is often omitted but it's assumed that it will be something bad. Something like "Pay me the money, or else I'll break your fingers".